# How to connect vga monitor to alienware 14?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have only vga supported monitor, and have converter from vga to hdmi.
But when i connect this to Alienware 14 laptop it is not working. I connected another dell laptop then VGA only monitor is working fine.

Googled results - no way converting hdmi to vga.

Question: Is there any other converter cable available to convert to Alienware 14 HDMI to VGA only supported moniter.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from HDMI to VGA, you need what's called an **Active adapter**. This is because you're converting from digital to analog.

Example:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cable-Matters-Active-Female-Adapter/dp/B007SM7O2U

Comment: I have this cable and it is not working in Alienware 14 Laptop, other dell laptop it is working..